# plot 2 variables on Y axis, using ggvis in R

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
"YEAR","A","B"
2001,100,177 
2002,154,419 
2003,334,190
2012,301,90
```

.. and a lot more rows.

"YEAR" columns range from 2001 to 2013.
I have the dataset loaded in data.table "DT"

I want to plot a graph with YEAR on X axis, and line graphs for A and B on Y axis.

In other words, i have to combine these two graphs in one.

```
DT %>% ggvis(~YEAR, ~A) %>% layer_lines()
DT %>% ggvis(~YEAR, ~B) %>% layer_lines()
```

I know the way to do it with ggplot2 but couldn't find a way for ggvis.
It shall be great even if i could do it in shiny.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
library(ggvis)

DT %>% ggvis(x= ~YEAR) %>%
  layer_lines(y= ~A, stroke:='blue')   %>%
  layer_lines(y= ~B, stroke:='orange')
```

I assume that you need different colors for each line as well to be able to distinguish the groups so I added the `stroke` argument.

Output:

[image]

It would probably be even better if you melt the data.frame first and then plot with the stroke argument which would return a legend as well. Like this:

```
library(reshape2)
DT2 <- melt(DT, 'YEAR', c('A','B'))
DT2 %>% ggvis(~YEAR, ~value, stroke=~variable) %>% layer_lines()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i had been looking for. Thanks a lot. 2nd option is even better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DT %>% ggvis(~YEAR, ~A) %>% layer_lines()%>%layer_lines(x=~YEAR, y=~B)
```

Comment: This produces an error (there is a minus sign before your YEAR) and there is no mention of the B group anyway..